# Laravel mail doesn't send when embedding link

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am developing password reset api on backend using Laravel 4.2. It is quite obvious that emails are not sending out if I embed http url . Normal email are sending out properly. Here is how I send email

**Laravel Function**

```
Mail::queue('emails.auth.confirm_password',$detail,function($message) use ($email)
{
     $message->from('abc@gmail.com', 'Test');
     $message->to($email)
     ->subject('Verification');
});
```

**emails.auth.confirm_password.php**

```
<p>We got a request to reset your Gurilla password. </p>

<a href="http://apitobackend/users/confirm_reset_password/{{$email}}" class="box">Reset Password</a>
<p>If you ignore this message, your password won't be changed</p>
```

I tried many alternatives with no luck. I believe sth weird going on. Might some expert help :-). thanks

Comment: Are you sure they're not sending out? Did you check your mailserver log? Maybe they're going out, but being blocked by a spam filter at the receiving end.

Comment: I'm not receiving email once i put hyper link. i checked spam as well. there is nth.

Comment: Some malware filters are sensitive to links, and they don't put the mail in the spam folder, they just drop it. Did you check your mailserver log to see if the mail is being sent?

Comment: you mean laravel mail function log? iv never checked the mail server log before. i will search for it and get bk to u. thanks

Comment: @Barmar I am still finiding a way to check mail server logs. Is there any alternatives not to being blocked my mail server ?

Comment: I don't know Laravel or SwiftMailer, but I really doubt they're doing this. It's most probably happening in the generic mail software. Does it happen when you send to all different domains?

Comment: If you're using a hosted server, it could be happening in your provider.

Comment: @Barmer it is not hosted server. most receipt are gmail users.